# How to add a button in admin form?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have add a button within admin form as follows.

```
$fieldset->addField('registered', 'button', array(
'label' => Mage::helper('core')->__('Send e-mail to all registered customers'),
'value' => Mage::helper('core')->__('Button Caption'),
'name'  => 'registered',
'onclick' => "setLocation('{$this->getUrl('*/*/registeremail')}')",
));
```

The functionality of this field working properly but the button does not appear properly. It appears as follows.

[image]

How to appear this button as normal magento button?

I have tried with

`'after_element_html' => '<button type="button" onclick="setLocation('{$this->getUrl('*/*/registeremail')}')">All Registered</button>'`

But onclick call is wrong.

Comment: try adding class form-button

Comment: @gulshanmaurya does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
$fieldset->addField('registered', 'button', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('core')->__('Send e-mail to all registered customers'),
            'value' => Mage::helper('core')->__('Button Caption'),
            'name'  => 'registered',
            'class' => 'form-button',
            'onclick' => "setLocation('{$this->getUrl('*/*/registeremail')}')",
        ));
```

This works for me.[image]